# In ggplot, how can I pass the name of my y column as a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a plot with ggplot but I do not know the name of the y column in advance.  Instead the name of the y column is contained in the variable yname.  This obviously doesn't work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=yname))
```

Because ggplot looks for a column in df that is literally named "yname".  How can I pass the name of the y column to ggplot as a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `aes_string`:

```
library(ggplot2)
yname <- "a"
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10), a=runif(10))
ggplot(df, aes_string(x="x", y=yname)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: `aes_string` is soft deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55133909/5477070 for a more up to date answer.