# standard eval with ggplot2 without `aes_string()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-evaluation

I'd like to pass a quoted string to a function that calls ggplot2.

```
library(magrittr); library(ggplot2)
g1 <- function( variable ) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes_string("wt", variable, size="carb")) +
    geom_point()
}
g1("mpg")
```

This works well, but the [v3.1.0 documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html) advocates quasiquotation and the NSE `aes()`.

> All these functions are soft-deprecated. Please use tidy evaluation idioms instead (see the quasiquotation section in aes() documentation).

But the [`aes()` examples](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html) use NSE (*ie*, `g1(mpg)` instead of `g1("mpg")`). Likewise, these SO solutions use either NSE values or `aes_()`/`aes_string()`.

- [Use dplyr SE with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279287)
- [How to use dplyr's enquo and quo_name in a function with tidyr and ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405843)
- [Why does this aes tidyeval example from ggplot documentation throw an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944004)

I'd like the function to accept a SE/quoted string, to accommodate a character vector, like:

```
variables <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")
variables %>% 
  lapply(g1)
```

Comment: See this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755181/786542

Comment: Do I understand the difference between this and @Croote's response? This uses `ensym()` instead of `sym()`?  Any other differences, or advantages in stability?

Comment: See this https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this using the `!!` operator on the variable after call to `sym`. This will unquote and evaluate `variable` in the surrounding environement.

```
library(rlang)
g1 <- function( variable ) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = !! sym(variable) , size = "carb")) +
    geom_point()
}
g1("mpg")

variables <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")
variables %>% 
  lapply(g1)
```

Answer (score 4):

A work-around is to substitute a common name for the variable name of interest in your function:

```
g1 <- function( variable ) {
  colnames(mtcars) <- gsub(variable, "variable", colnames(mtcars))
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=variable, size=carb)) +
    geom_point() + ylab(variable)
}

variables <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")
variables %>% 
  lapply(g1)
```

Comment: This is nice, especially if there are multiple mapped variables that need to be dynamic, so each variable doesn't need to operators/functions (ie, `!!` and `sym()`).

Comment: Btw, I might change `gsub()` to `sub()` and tighten up the pattern so it had to match exactly (not just somewhere in the middle of the variable name).  Maybe something like `paste0("^", variable, "$")`.  Or replace the names with `dplyr::rename()` and I guess `!!`.