# standard eval with `dplyr::count()`

Tags: r, dplyr, standard-evaluation

How can I pass a character vector to [`dplyr::count()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html).

```
library(magrittr)
variables <- c("cyl", "vs")

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::count_(variables)
```

This works well, but [dplyr v0.8](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases/tag/v0.8.0) throws the warning:

> count_() is deprecated. 
>      Please use count() instead
>
> The 'programming' vignette or the tidyeval book can help you
>      to program with count() : https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org

I'm not seeing standard evaluation examples of quoted names or of `dplyr::count()` in https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html or other chapters of the current versions of the [*tidyeval* book](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org) and [*Programming with dplyr*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

My two best guesses after reading this documenation and [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132771/standard-eval-with-ggplot2-without-aes-string) is

```
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::count(!!variables)

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::count(!!rlang::sym(variables))
```

which throw these two errors:

> Error: Column `<chr>` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one,
>   not 2
>
> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols

Comment: Make it `!!!rlang::syms(variables)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a list of symbols from strings, you want `rlang::syms` (not `rlang::sym`). For unquoting a list or a vector, you want to use `!!!` (not `!!`). The following will work:

```r
library(magrittr)

variables <- c("cyl", "vs")

vars_sym <- rlang::syms(variables)
vars_sym
#> [[1]]
#> cyl
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> vs

mtcars %>%
  dplyr::count(!!! vars_sym)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>     cyl    vs     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4     0     1
#> 2     4     1    10
#> 3     6     0     3
#> 4     6     1     4
#> 5     8     0    14
```

Comment: You might clarify the term "unquoting" as specifically referring to converting a character vector  to an R "symbol", since the term quoting might alternatively be interpreted as the use of the function `quote`, for which one form of "reversal" might then be accomplished with `as.character` which would then deliver a different sort of "quoted" value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs) %>%
  tally()
```

This gives

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl    vs     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     0     1
2     4     1    10
3     6     0     3
4     6     1     4
5     8     0    14
```

Comment: The OP is trying to do this programmatically, such as with tidyeval, not by supplying specific column names in `group_by`